# Finding creator of crashed thread in OS X/gdb?

Tags: macos, gdb, pthreads

let's say I'm in gdb and have a call stack like this:

```
Thread 24 (process 6449):
#0 0x994010e2 in semaphore_wait_signal_trap ()
#1 0x9942ec9c in _pthread_cond_wait ()
#2 0x9947745f in pthread_cond_wait ()
#3 0x92ed1ccd in jpegdecompress_MPLoop ()
#4 0x9942e7fd in _pthread_start ()
#5 0x9942e682 in thread_start ()
```

How do I find out who created that thread?

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can't: the pthread library doesn't have any reason to record and store that info.

In applications that create only a handful of threads, this usually isn't needed either -- if you know that it's the jpegdecompressor thread that crashed, and you only create one of them, then it's trivial to tell *where* that thread was created.

If you really need the answer, you'll have to record the stack trace at the time of `pthread_create` call, and pass that to the new thread to save away in some thread-local.