# How to know who started a thread

Tags: multithreading, gdb

I am trying to debug a crash in gdb where is core dumped on this thread. There is other 40+ threads going on at the same time. How do I figure out where this thread 42 is started from?

Also, why the last line (frame #0) is not showing up?

```
Thread 42 (Thread 0x2aaba65ce940 (LWP 15854)):
#0  0x0000003a95605b03 in __nptl_deallocate_tsd () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x0000003a9560684b in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#2  0x0000003a946d526d in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#3  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

I am using gdb version 7.7

Comment: A more interesting question is why so many threads? Guess you like the processor doing context switching rather that doing the task in hand!

Comment: I can't control.. this is a very large code base

Comment: Very good question.  I don't understand those downvotes without a commented explanation.  Often you don't know about threads created by libraries you're using, and want to trace the problem to your code. Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6069484/finding-creator-of-crashed-thread-in-os-x-gdb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I figure out where this thread 42 is started from?

You can't: neither GDB, nor the OS keeps track of "who started this thread". (It is also often quite useless to know where a particular thread was created).

What you could do is either put instrumentation into your own calls to `pthread_create` and log "thread X created thread Y", or use `catch syscall clone`, and print creation stack traces in GDB, then match them later to the crashed thread (match its `LWP` to the return value of `clone` earler).

> Also, why the last line (frame #0) is not showing up?

You mean frame `#3`. It doesn't exist -- `clone` is where the thread is borne (comes to existence).

P.S. Installing libc debug symbols so you can see *where* inside `__nptl_deallocate_tsd` the thread crashed is more likely to provide clues than knowing thread creation details.